# Ubuntu Server 20.04 - Power Button does not do anything

Tags: ubuntu, power-management

I am trying to figure out why I can no longer turn off my server using the power button. I first noticed that it no longer worked after I installed Transmission.

Steps I have tried:

- I removed Transmission
- I reinstalled acpi and acpid
- I then removed acpid after learning that logind handles the power button
- I confirmed that logind is running, and journalctl shows that it catches the power button press
- I checked that `HandlePowerKey=poweroff` is set in my `logind.conf`

Is there anything else I can try to do?

Thanks